# My Samsung 700Z won't startup

Tags: windows, boot, laptop, battery, updates

My samsung 700Z will not start. It won't show the that the battery is charging and I can hold the power button but it won't do anything. I shut my computer down when it was updating because it was on update 39/50 for 1 hour. I have an SSD and a i5  2,5GHz and 4GB of RAM.

This is the model number:
NP700Z3C-S01NL

I hope there is someway of hard resetting the laptop or reaching the SSD, so I can at least backup my files.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the drive from your computer and copy files using another computer. The update was probably stopped at the "right" moment for Windows to fail.

If you can boot from DVD you can see if you can get your hands on a Microsoft DaRT DVD for your Windows version.

You can also try to boot from a Windows Repair DVD, which can be made from another computer as long as it's the same Windows version (bit version has to match too!)